# Upgrade to Magento 2.4.6 and Elasticsearch results in elasticsearch error and no products on Category pages

Tags: magento, magento2, opensearch

We have updated working store to 2.4.6 and switched from ElasticSearch to OpenSearch. All 2.4.6 prereqs are met and connection to OpenSearch is successful. Search results show categories and individual items as expected. Individual item pages work properly but category pages show We can't find products matching the selection. We have tried the usual recommendations (upgrade, static content deploy, cache flush, di:compile, indexer:reindex, etc) with no success. We have verified that products are visible, enabled, have quantity, instock and are assigned to category. The products do show in the appropriate category on the backend category page list of products.

The following error appears in the exception log after category page is loaded.

```
{"exception":"[object] (OpenSearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"x_content_parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"[1:107] [field_sort] failed to parse field [order]\"}],\"type\":\"x_content_parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"[1:107] [field_sort] failed to parse field [order]\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"No enum constant org.opensearch.search.sort.SortOrder.\"}},\"status\":400}
```

We would greatly appreciate any suggestions to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you find any correct solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration there might be open search select as a default value. Change it to elastic search 7 and make sure correct elastic search version installed on server. (I have 7.17 version)

Reindex and then Clean cache.